# Extract Information From "inxi -ni" as key value pair

Tags: ubuntu, bash, ubuntu-20.04

Team,

I need to extract the output from "inxi -ni" as key value pair. Eg if I need only "IP v4"

OS: Ubuntu V-20

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
address=`inxi -ni | grep "IP v4" | cut -d' ' -f3`
echo "IPv4=$address"
```

- Use `grep` to regex match "IP v4"
- Then use `cut` to parse field 3 unlimited by space.
- Save it to `$address` variable
- Then display it using `echo` command

Comment: Thanks  for your detailed explanation. This is what I want.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have a current inxi, or you update your old inxi, this -y1 output option was introduced recently (3.1.03 or 04 I think):

```
inxi -nizy1
Network:
  Device-1: Intel I211 Gigabit Network
    driver: igb
    IF: enp6s0
      state: up
      speed: 1000 Mbps
      duplex: full
      mac: <filter>
      IP v4: <filter>
        scope: global
      IP v6: <filter>
        scope: link
  IF-ID-1: vboxnet0
    state: down
    mac: <filter>
  WAN IP: <filter>
```

For all 3.x inxi:

```
inxi -niz --output json --output-file print
{"000#1#0#Network":[{"001#1#1#Device":"Intel I211 Gigabit Network","002#1#2#driver":"igb"},{"002#0#3#speed":"1000 Mbps","001#0#3#state":"up","003#0#3#duplex":"full","004#0#3#mac":"<filter>","000#1#2#IF":"enp6s0"},{"002#0#4#scope":"global","001#1#3#IP v4":"<filter>"},{"001#1#3#IP v6":"<filter>","002#0#4#scope":"link"},{"001#0#2#state":"down","002#0#2#mac":"<filter>","000#1#1#IF-ID":"vboxnet0"},{"000#0#1#WAN IP":"<filter>"}]}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get the value of the selected key with this:

```
inxi -ni --output json --output-file print | python3 -m json.tool | jq '.[] | . []' | sed 's/".*#/"/' | jq 'select(has("IP v4"))'

{
  "scope": "global",
  "IP v4": "192.168.1.91/24"
}
{
  "scope": "global",
  "IP v4": "172.17.0.1/16"
}
{
  "scope": "global",
  "IP v4": "192.168.192.119/24"
}
```